# Provide all childs of a class with dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

im creating a highly modular application, i have a lot of clases that need to be injected, all of them are childs (not direct childs) of the same class, none of them have constructor parameters.

I want to avoid having to create a "@Provides" method for each one of them in my module.

Is there a way to tell dagger to automatically provide all the classes that implement a base interface? Or is it possible to do it myself using reflection?

Im using dagger-android with kotlin

**Update**: Ill post some code to illustrate

In one of the modules i have this interface

```
interface ExampleClass: BaseExample {

    fun doSomething()

    }
}
```

Then in the main app i implement it

```
class ExampleClassImpl @Inject constructor() : ExampleClass { 
    override fun doSomething(){
    }
}
```

The class where i need it is a Viewmodel created with dagger so inject works on the constructor.

```
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(val exmpl :ExampleClass) : BaseViewModel { 

}
```

I want to inject that ExampleClassImpl, to do that i need to create a @module with a method annotated with @Provides or @Bind and return that class.

Without the provider i get an error at compile time:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.myapp.ExampleClassImpl cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: Why would you need to create a `@Provides` method for each one? Can't you just annotate each class constructor with `@Inject` or am I missing something?

Comment: I already have @Inject on the constructor, but i still need dagger to provide those classes

Comment: If you have `@Inject` in each subclass constructor then Dagger will automatically provide these classes. You don't need `@Provides` methods.

Comment: That does not seem right, if i remove the "@Provides" method i get this: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.myapp.ExampleClass cannot be provided without an "@Provides-annotated" method.

Comment: Assuming `ExampleClass` is a concrete class, are you annotating its constructor? 
 Please post some code so we can understand what you're doing.

Comment: i´ve added example code

Comment: Post also the code where you are trying to inject `ExampleClassImpl`

Comment: there it is, nothing fancy, i must be missing something if this is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

You want to inject `ExampleClass`, but Dagger only knows about `ExampleClassImpl`. How would Dagger know that you want that specific subclass?
Moreover, you say you have *many* subclasses that you want to inject. How would Dagger know which one to provide to a constructor expecting the base class?

If you want `ExampleViewModel` to get an instance of `ExampleClassImpl` then you can simply change the declaration to:

```
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(val exmpl :ExampleClassImpl)
```

Doing so you lose the ability to swap the constructor argument with a different implementation of `ExampleClass`.

The alternative is to have one `@Named @Provides` method per subclass. So something like:

```
// In your module
@Provides
@Named("impl1")
fun provideExampleClassImpl1(impl: ExampleClassImpl): ExampleClass = impl
```

```
// When using the named dependency
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(@Named("impl1") val exmpl :ExampleClass)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the viewmodel is in a different module and doesn't know about the implementation and the alternative is in fact creating a provider, exactly what i want to avoid.
So my only option is a way of telling dagger to automatically provide all the classes that inherit from BaseExample interface in my module